# Pass IAM identity of AWS API-Gateway calls to backend server

Tags: amazon-web-services, saas, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

We want to set-up an existing API as SAAS using AWS
Our code has been deployed via elastic-beanstalk, and we created access to the methods via Gateway to manage permissions.

We're now trying to log the user's activity, for billing purposes

Currently, the best solution we found involves a full logging of the calls (Enabled CloudWatch Logs + Log full requests/responses data), which looks quite heavy, and may even end up beeing expensive.

We reworked the request body in the integration request, by adding a mapping template for the body, but this seems heavy and complicated, whe hope there was a better solution we missed.

Basically, we replaced the default "passthrough" with a generated basic "passthrough" code, and added a value "MyUserArn" : "$context.identity.userArn" in it, which fills the requests body with a large mess, but looks like "The most reliable way to avoid to breaking something".

We'd like to just add the IAM user identifier in a header, or query string parameter, but failed to find if this is even possible. Several posts mention an "Invoke with caller credentials" option, but we didn't find this either.

Is is something related to cognito or something else ?

Are we doing something wrong ?

Comment: Could you clarify what a "large mess" is?

Comment: Using the default "passthrough" for body creation adds a lot of details in the output body (body content is moved to a variable `"body-json"`, and many data like `"query params"`, `"content-type"` and `"date"` are added.  I used this because I thought it could be necessary (in case of non-empty values necessary to passthrough), but I could update that point now, since I replaced all this with a simple output of `$input.json('$'),
"userArn" : "$context.identity.userArn"`.
Filling the body of requests which originally have an empty one doesn't really looks like something I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple different options for getting this information, both of which have trade offs:

1. Your current solution pulling the value from `$context.identity` in a mapping template and sending to your Lambda as part of the body. It seems like you are opposed to this given your "large mess" comment, but ultimately you have control over the content passed to your Lambda.
2. Enable "user caller credentials" on your method and then use identity value **inside your Lambda**. Currently this only works if you've used credentials vended from a Cognito authentication flow and does require that Lambda invocation also be part of your role policy, but doesn't require any modification of the template.

**UPDATE** Apologies, I somehow missed you were using Beanstalk and not Lambda. You can definitely just add a header to your integration request and simply have pull its value from `$context.identity.userArn`.

**UPDATE 2** Double apologies, when using context variables in headers, you omit the $ so you need to use `context.identity.userArn`.

Comment: Glad to see its possible, but I didn't find any clue about the syntax for adding a variable as value for a header.  The mentionned syntax is `method.request.{param_location}.{param_name}`, but it's not very clear to me.
I tried `GET.routeName.{$context.identity.userArn}.{"param"}` but seems I was wrong.  `$context.identity.userArn` doesn't work either... I only managed to add constant headers, with simple quotes :/

Comment: @Balmipour $context.identity.userArn should work. The docs are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference). Just to make sure, you've enabled AWS_IAM authentication on your API, correct?

Comment: When I put this value, I get `Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: $context.identity.userArn]`.  _(setting this in the "Mapped from" column of my header, at integration request phase.)_
And yes, IAM auth is of course enabled, but anyway, it just outputs an empty value on resources which don't need auth, not an error.

Comment: (forgot to mention I already browsed lot of docs, including this one.)  I just read the "Set up Method and Integration" part, but didn't find any information about putting _variables_ in headers.

Comment: You can't but variables in headers, only a single value or a constant string. Unfortunately I forgot the format is slightly different when using context variables in header mappings, see update above.

Comment: You really don't have to apologize when you save my day (or week).  Infinite thanks !